# Spring configure bean with properties

Tags: java, spring

I'm new in Spring, and want to figure out how to inject value from properties file.

I have component with `Value` annotation:

```java
@Component
public class ConfigProp {

    private final String login;

    public ConfigProp(@Value("${login}") String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ConfigProp{" +
            "login='" + login + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
}
```

then, I have main class:

```java
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        var context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConfigProp.class);
        context.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer());
        
        var cp = context.getBean(ConfigProp.class);
        System.out.println(cp);
    }
}
```

Additionally I have `application.properties` file
with content:

```
login=some_login
```

And when I launching my app I'm getting `ConfigProp{login='${login}'}`

Yes, I know, I may annotate `ConfigProp` with `@PropertySource(path-to-properties)` annotation, but it's not a good solution, because in the Prod I may want to use another properties file,

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Why do you need AnnotationConfigApplicationContext? This should be supported by Spring without extra changes

Comment: @vladtkachuk What else I can use? Because all tutorials advice to use it

Comment: I believe there is a default spring support for this, have you tried not setting that bean postprocessor?